# Save a figure with multiple extensions?

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, is there any (especially clever) way to save a figure with multiple extensions?

Use case: I generally want .png's for quick-look examination, uploading to the web, etc.  But for publication-quality figures, I want .pdf or .eps files.  Often, I want all 3.

It's not hard to do:

```
for suffix in 'png eps pdf'.split():
    pl.savefig(figname+"."+suffix)
```

but it does involve a lot of rewriting code (since I generally just have `savefig(figname+'.png')` everywhere right now), and this seems like an easy case for a convenient wrapper function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you always do

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
...
pl.savefig
```

then you could concievably reassign `pl.savefig` in one place and it would affect all places.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
def save_figs(fn,types=('.pdf',)):
    fig = pl.gcf()
    for t in types:
        fig.savefig(fn+t)
pl.savefig = save_figs
```

If you usually do

```
fig=pl.figure()
fig.savefig(...)
```

then that will require more effort.

Comment: you can monkeypatch classes just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the file type as shown in [the documentation for savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) by using `format`. But as far as I know you can only specify a single format.

While not especially clever, to minimised rewriting code you should write a `save_fig` function. This can then handle automatically creating appropriate file names and a quality.

```
def save_fig(fig_name, quality="quick-look"):
    if "quick-look" in quality:
         # save fig with .png etc
    if "pub-qual" in quality:
         # save fig with increased dpi etc etc.
```

Probably not the answer you're looking for as it will require you to rewrite every savefig however I feel this kind of thing can help reduce the amount of repeated code overall.

Comment: That's a nice approach, and there's a good chance I'll go with it; I think it would be nice if matplotlib allowed another syntax for saving similar to this: `savefig(prefix,types=('png','pdf'))`, which is along the lines of what you've shown.

Comment: I would write your wrapper function to take a list of extensions, and then monkey-patch it in